# Polynomial Remainder / Generating Function Remainder

Tags: calculus

Can someone help direct me towards information on calculating the polynomial remainder?

I know how to do the basics, but what if I don't have access to the polynomial in expanded form?

For example, $\frac{1}{1-x}$ represents the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^\infty{x^i}$.  I want to be able to find the remainder using an expression like the fraction.

Please help explain where I can find more resources on this.  I'm not a math expert, so something very readable would be great.  However, I'm willing to learn the math if I need to.

Could someone help me find resources with the equivalent and generating functions?

Just to show that this operation is well defined, Dr. Herwig Hauser has written a paper concerning the operation [here](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/Publications/linear_recurrences_and_powerseries_division.pdf)

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is a *power series* not a *polynomial*. You can still perform division with these but there is no remainder, to derive the 'formula' for division just invert multiplication (look at the diagonals of the infinite product).

Comment: I was able to get a remainder in Mathematica using their PolynoialRemainder method with two generating functions as the polynomials.  I'm interested in this result.

Comment: This is not the right site to ask questions about Mathematica.

Comment: Please pardon my comment.  I'm simply trying to state that I believe the operation is well defined.  I'm adding a link to a paper detailing this above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you're after is on page 31 in Wilf's [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html):

> **Proposition**. A formal power series $f=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$ has a reciprocal if and only if $a_0 \neq 0$.  In that case the reciprocal is unique.

Comment: That may help. You have me wondering how to calculate the reciprocal. Unfortunately, I'm working with a "power series" where the powers range from $-n$ to $n$; it may be easier to think of it as a "special" Laurent series. I'm exploring methods to find the constant term. I've heard that there's an easy way to extract the residue for the Laurent series. Unfortunately, I remember that attempting to modify that method failed for some reason.